# Live Quidditch viewing

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

The wizarding world seems to rely mainly on newspapers (the Daily Prophet) for their news. They have no T.V. although they do have radio.

The wizarding world treats Quidditch like Muggles treat football so I would expect a lot of interest in new/breaking Quiddith scores. As this is the case do wizards have some way of watching live Quidditch matches other than going to the event?

Comment: A lot of Muggles are satisfied with listening to sports commentary on the radio, so they at least have that. As for watching it, that's a good question.

Comment: You got a fascination with the number 3? http://i.stack.imgur.com/TgHQC.jpg

Comment: @Mooz Of course.

Comment: @Mooz - We collaborated very carefully to get all those.

Comment: Half-Life 3 confirmed!

Comment: Out-of-universe - Quidditch will be a bad candidate for showing on TV - with the unknown length of the game, the TV hosts will have hard time managing their program.

Comment: Presumably, with Portkeys, Apparition and things, going to watch it in person would be easier for wizards that for most football fans, for example. Plus a lower population to serve.

Comment: @vap78 They could have a dedicated Quidditch channel.

Comment: @ThruGog In big tournaments they would sell out though and then people would still want to see the matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The ministry forbids it

> While they have no need of mundane domestic objects such as dishwashers or vacuum cleaners, some members of the magical community are amused by Muggle television, **and a few firebrand wizards even went so far, in the early eighties, as to start a British Wizarding Broadcasting Corporation, in the hope that they would be able to have their own television channel. The project foundered at an early stage, as the Ministry of Magic refused to countenance the broadcasting of wizarding material on a Muggle device**, which would (it was felt) almost guarantee serious breaches of the International Statute of Secrecy.
>   <sub>([Pottermore - Technology](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/technology))</sub>

Wizards who are unable to attend must read about it in the papers. (Quidditch matches will often last longer than a day, so they can still almost "follow" the match as it goes.) By matches such as the 2014 Quidditch World Cup, [the Daily Prophet will even print live coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmgVb.jpg) (whatever that's supposed to mean).

Comment: Print live coverage, some kind of magic updating text?

Comment: @Bellerephon - Well that was how it worked on the "very magical" Pottermore. Not sure about in the Wizarding World. While it would answer up the Nicolas Flamel dating inconsistency, it would probably raise more problems than it would solve.